# How to remove near-duplicate links from Chrome's Omnibox auto-suggestions

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

I'm mainly using, and in this question specifying, Chrome (current version as of writing: 63.0.3239.84). In Chrome I visit sites, for example Reddit, and if I enter:

`reddit.com/r/jq`

The Omnibox automatically suggests both:

`reddit.com/r/jquery/new`, and `reddit.com/r/jquery/new/`

[image: Screenshot of Google Chrome showing near-duplicate entries in the Omnibox suggestions]

This is, admittedly a minor issue but it does result in suggestions taking up more space than (seems) necessary; is there any way to prevent either one of those suggestions – with, or without, the trailing `/` character – appearing in the suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the suggestions drop-down appearing like the example in your image, use the keyboard arrow keys to highlight the autocomplete entry you want removed and either:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>, or <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>

to delete the entry from appearing as a possible autocomplete value.

Comment: Curran: thank you so much! I have edited your answer a little (pending peer review), should it be approved do feel free to roll-back if you'd prefer :)